# Javascript Infinity-- (infinity minus minus) yields Infinity

Tags: javascript, infinity

I am looking at JavaScript's number type system.

I'm using Chrome, When I evaluate `15--` for a number literal I get a `ReferenceError` since it makes no sense to decrement a constant.

When I evaluate `var x=10;x--;` as expected everything works.

Expectantly `var a=Infinity;a--` evaluates to `Infinity`, this all makes sense and is in accordance [to the javascript language spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/).

However to my surprise `Infinity--` and `Infinity++` evaluate to `Infinity` unlike other literals.

This also happens for `Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY` which is the same.

**tl;dr :**

Why does `Infinity--` yield infinity as a result when `15--` and `(new Number(15))--` yield a reference error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Infinity` as used in your example is not actually a value but refers to the [`Infinity` property of the global object](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1.1.2):

> ### 15.1 The Global Object
>
> [...]
>
> #### 15.1.1 Value Properties of the Global Object
>
> [...]
>
> **15.1.1.2 Infinity**
> The value of `Infinity` is `+∞` (see [8.5](http://es5.github.com/#x8.5)). This property has the attributes { [[Writable]]: `false`, [[Enumerable]]: `false`, [[Configurable]]: `false` }.

So, `Infinity--` is the same as `window.Infinity--` which is perfectly valid.

Comment: Thanks! Also worth noting that Infinity.valueOf()-- does not work :)

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no such thing as a the number infinity, it is a concept, and thus in coding it isn't built as other constants but as an object like null or undefined but with some properties thrown in to make it behave nice with Math methods.

Comment: This actually has nothing to do with infinity or numbers, only with how a symbol is resolved in JavaScript.

Comment: Of course there is a number infinity. For example if you close the field of natural numbers N under the limit operator and look at the limit of the series f(n) = n , the result of the limit is infinity. Also, I was asking why I can _assign_ to it